# Wpf ListView trigger SourceUpdate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

How do i trigger the SourceUpdate of my wpf listview?

This is my xaml

```
<ListView DataContext="{StaticResource vmInstance}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}" BorderBrush="Beige" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding lstExternal}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ItemChanged}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceUpdated">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SourceUpdated}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View >                     
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public static RelayCommand SourceUpdated { get; set; }

//on initialize
SourceUpdated = new RelayCommand(SourceUpdateEvent);

public void SourceUpdateEvent()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Updated");
}
```

Why does SourceUpdateEvent doesn't run?

Am I using the wrong event?

Thank you

Comment: A command is not an event...When exactly do you want your command to get executed? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to execute a method when the itemsource of the listview is changed or updated.

Comment: Then it doesn't make much sense to subscribe to the SouceUpdated event in the view. You should handle this logic in the view model. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to execute a method when the itemsource of the listview is changed or updated

Then bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to a source property of your view model

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ...>
```

...and invoke your command in the setter of this source property:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourType> _sourceCollection;
public ObservableCollection<YourType> SourceCollection
{
    get { return _sourceCollection; }
    set
    {
        _sourceCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        SourceUpdated.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

This is the (only) correct way to solve this using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the ListView object as a parameter to `Execute()` instead of `null`?